# AJAX post and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'have and AJAX post request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var URL = "someURL";
    $.post(URL, this.id, function(data, status) {
      var val = parseInt(document.getElementById(this.data).innerHTML)
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val + 1 ;
      document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="/book/test/1">Read</a>
<span id="${book.id}">
```

This script is working as expected; a button with number in it increase by one.
The problems are:

- A refresh of the page occurs. On button click it reloads all on the page.
- I'm not able to disable the button after the change

In short I need a count button which increase by 1 and can be changed once per user.

**Update** It seems that reload it's related to another function defined as

`$(document).ready(function() {`

So i have one in the body and one in the head.

Comment: Call `$(this).off('click')` in the click handler for the span to stop users from clicking it again. There's nothing in your example which would cause the page to reload, so we can't really offer any help with that.

Comment: I'll give a try. Maybe is not page reload but only the js functions. Which I read can be due to problem in the js. I've tried to add JSFiddle without success

Comment: SO what is `id`?

Comment: id is from is coming from another framework. In this case is integer 1,2,3. Which is working fine. I'm new to AJAX and it's possible this to not be the best solution. But it's the only one working so far.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it refreshes the page, you're sending it a link to go to via href. Instead, remove the href, and put an onclick event and handler. Replace your anchor tag, with this:

```
<a onclick="runFunction()">Read</a>
```

And replace your script, with this.

```
<script>
function runFunction(){
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       var URL="someURL";
       $.post(URL,
        this.id,
       function(data,status){
           var val = parseInt(document.getElementById(this.data).innerHTML)
           document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val + 1 ;
           document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
       });
   });
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: The OP is attaching the event handler to the `span`, not the `a`. The `runFunction()` in your example will attach the event handler, but It will only do any actual work on successive clicks, but then it would repeat that click handler. I'd suggest using an unobtrusive event handler in the proper manner if you want to do it this way.